# Dagger2 Inject a navigator in a viewmodel

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am using Android's ViewModel lib and I want to inject a Navigator in a ViewModel which is scoped inside App, but my navigator is dependent of activity. I don't know how to inject it. I'll copy and paste some files here but my project can be found [here](https://github.com/ViperAlpha/VehicleMonitor) and the files I mention is under 'app/src/main/java/app/vehiclemonitor/' + 'app/' or 'viewmodel' or 'features/home'

VmAppComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {VMAppModule.class, VMApiServiceModule.class, SchedulerModule.class, ViewModelModule.class})
public interface VMAppComponent {

    void inject(VMApp app);

    HomeActivityComponent injectHomeActivity(BaseActivityModule module);

    AddEditVehicleActivityComponent injectAddEditVehicleActivity(BaseActivityModule module);
}
```

ViewModelModule.class

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(HomeViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindHomeViewModel(HomeViewModel homeViewModel);

    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory factory);

}


public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    @NonNull    
    private HomeNavigator navigationProvider;

    @NonNull
    private BaseSchedulerProvider schedulerProvider;

    @Inject
    public HomeViewModel(@NonNull final BaseSchedulerProvider schedulerProvider) {
        this.schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
    }

    // @Inject
    // public HomeViewModel(@NonNull HomeNavigator navigationProvider, @NonNull BaseSchedulerProvider schedulerProvider) {
    //  this.navigationProvider = navigationProvider;
    //  this.schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
    // }

    void handleAddButtonClick() {
        navigationProvider.addNewVehicle();
    }

    public void setNavigationProvider(final HomeNavigator navigationProvider) {
        this.navigationProvider = navigationProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your viewmodel should have a Navigator inside it? A viewmodel shouldn't have any reference to Activities or Views. You could try sending the navigation event from the activity to the viewmodel, then your viewmodel do what it needs to do and calls something in the activity to update the UI and perform the view switch... (Just thinking)

Comment: Well, it is a good point! I never thought I was referencing an activity indirectly inside a ViewModel, it will indeed cause a leak, but now, I don't know where would be a good idea to put it. Your idea is to the Activity use it?

Comment: maybe you can inject it to in your basefragment or baseactivity.

Comment: Yes, let the Activity reference the navigator

Comment: have you guys found any sample project that uses it this way?

Comment: Google Samples uses a navigator inside ViewModel... any comments about why? Or is it a mistake ?  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-rxjava/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksViewModel.java

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is a good question, a lot of developers had/have the same question and currently there isn't an official solution to this.

The only sure thing is:

> A `ViewModel` **should not** have references to Activities or Views in general.

What you should do is reading all this thread in GitHub https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/63, a lot of solutions have been posted and probably there is at least one good for you.

About the link you posted on [googlesamples and blueprint](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-rxjava/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksViewModel.java), their `Navigator` is not good as you can think. It's still an example app and probably they removed some complexity to make the sample easier to understand for a wider set of developers.

I think a better approach is the one provided in [this sample repo](https://github.com/fabioCollini/ArchitectureComponentsDemo) which completely remove references to Activities. (It's made in Kotlin, I don't know if you can emulate the same behaviours with Java but you could try at least).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Why is it different? I mean, I followed their implementation to do mine...

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't check all the code, I've updated the last part of my answer ;)

Comment: I've looked into the samples and it is the same navigator as GoogleSamples/GithubBrowserSample, it is just for one main activity routing. In my opinion, it is not maintainable having it all in one file... Maybe I'm looking for another

Comment: The link I've posted uses a better approach than the one in GitHubBrowserSample. It is based on the same sample but you can add how many activities you need. I don't know if I have the time to extend the sample to multiple activities just to showcase you the thing